# Transfer all combinations within a square matrix to data.frame columns

Tags: r, matrix

For those of you who are familiar with linear algebra and have done matrix operations in R before, this question will be very easy.

I have a matrix containing cultural characteristics of countries.

```
structure(c(4.36, 4.44, 4.04, 4.49, 4.09, 4.46, 3.81, 4.44, 3.4, 
3.09, 3.31, 3.7, 4.28, 4.62, 4.2, 4.05, 4.28, 3.72, 3.66, 4.49, 
4.17, 4.85, 5.18, 4.26, 4.29, 4.3, 3.83, 4.38, 4.74, 4.95, 5.33, 
4.82, 4.39, 5.16, 3.6, 4.58), .Dim = c(4L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Australia", "Austria", "Brazil", "Canada"), c("Performance.Orientation", 
    "Future.Orientation", "Gender.Egalitarianism", "Assertiveness", 
    "Humane.orientation", "in.group.collectivism", "institutional.collectivism", 
    "power.concentration.decentralization..power.distance.", 
    "uncertainty.avoidance")))
```

Based on this matrix, I would like to calculate the following cultural distance index:

```html
<img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?CDj=\sum_{i=1}^{9}\frac{(I_i_j-I_i_u)^2/Vi}{9}" title="CDj=\sum_{i=1}^{9}\frac{(I_i_j-I_i_u)^2/Vi}{9}" />
```

where Iij is the index of the i-th cultural practices dimension and j-th country, Iiu is the index of the i-th cultural practices dimension of the u-th country, Vt is the variance of index of the i-th cultural practices dimension, and CDju is the cultural distance of the j-th country from the u-th country.

The result of this calculation should be a squared matrix with row and column dimensions euqal to the number of countries.

Once the square matrix has been computed, I would like to copy all the entries of the matrix in two data frame columns. I would like the result to be something like

```
Country1      Country2    CD

Australia    Australia     0
Australia      Austria   3,2
Australia       Brazil   5,4
...             ....     ...
```

While trying to accomplish this I had many problems - like, I was unable to get the diagonal of a matrix obtaining a matrix that has values on the diagonal and is zero off-diagonal. I would be very glad if someone could suggest a solution.

Many thanks for the help!
Riccardo

Comment: To construct a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements in a vector, `vec`, just use `diag(vec)`. To construct all the two-way combinations of a vector use `combn(vec, 2)`. The title of this question doesn't seem to match the described task.

Comment: To accomplish the square matrix to long dataframe just use `as.data.frame.table(M)`

Comment: @BondedDust thanks a lot for the advice. This will help me with the matrix reshape. Regarding how to do the matrix calculations, I will ask another question focused on that.